# Action in a short exact sequence

Tags: group-theory, exact-sequence, finitely-generated

Let $1 \mapsto A \mapsto B \mapsto C \mapsto 1$ be a short exact sequence of groups and assume that $B$ is finitely generated.

My question is whether the action of $C$ on $A$ (by conjugation) has finitely many orbits.

If $C$ is finitely presented, I think that it is true. Since $C$ is finitely presented, $A$ is finitely generated as a normal subgroup of $B$, in other words, the action of $C$ on $A$ has finitely many orbits.

Nevertheless, if we do not ask $C$ to be finitely presented (we just know that since $B$ is finitely generated, so is $C$), I do not know whether the following argument is correct:

The group $B$ is finitely generated and it is generated by $\langle A, \tilde{C} \rangle$, where $\tilde{C}$ is a lift of $C$ in $B$. Then, there are elements $a_1,\dots,a_k$ in $A$ and $\tilde{c_{1}},\dots,\tilde{c_{n}}$ in $\tilde{C}$ such that $B=\langle a_1,\dots,a_k,\tilde{c_{1}},\dots,\tilde{c_{n}}\rangle$. Hence, $A$ is generated by $a_1,\dots,a_k$ and their conjugates by words in $\{\tilde{c_1},\dots,\tilde{c_{k}}\}$. In particular, the action of $C$ on $A$ has finitely many orbits because $$A=\bigcup_{i\in \{1,\dots,k\}} C \cdot a_i.$$

Comment: $C$ does not necessarily act on $A$ by conjugation at all without additional assumptions.

Comment: @EricWofsey No? I thought that the action in a SES, for example when using spectral sequences, was always by conjugation... Can you extend more your answer, please? I guess the problem is that the conjugation action needs to be well defined?

Comment: Right, why would the action be well-defined?  There is a conjugation action if you have a specific splitting $C\to B$ of the quotient map, or if $A$ is abelian (so it acts trivially on itself by conjugation).

Comment: @EricWofsey I see... So it is possible not to have an action of $C$ on $A$, but there is always an action of $C$ on $H_1(A;\mathbb{Z})$ for example?